# is it possible to get the IEditorPart from IFile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

i am looking a way of initiate editor using platform API.
is there any way to get the IEditorPart from IFile?

thanks

Comment: What if the file is opened in two editors at once?

Comment: @tobias_k that's not a problem  easy to to check by getting all open editors and iterate on them ... 'IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
   .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
   IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();'

Comment: So, you basically could loop all those editors, check whether the input is a `FileEditorInput`, and check whether the file is the one you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: that's not going to work for me. the IFile that i need to open is tab in multipage editor.. i can't directly initiate it with it editor, because i am running in to circle dependency. so i need some generic way to get the IEditorPart from IFile and then pass it to  multipage editor.

Comment: @greg-449 see my previews commit. thanks

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do. Please edit the question and add a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the solution, and i want to share it with the people that may have same issue.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorRegistry editorRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry();
EditorManager manager = ((WorkbenchPage) page).getEditorManager();
//the magic is here
IEditorDescriptor desc = editorRegistry.findEditor("com.Editor.ID");    
EditorReference result = new EditorReference(manager, new FileEditorInput(iFile), (EditorDescriptor)desc, null);    
IEditorPart editor = result.getEditor(true);
```